# SQL Select - inserting values if not exist from another table grouping by another value

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

```
@sales  --- where I register the daily number of sales
@o_date --- where I register the opening dates
```

I need to fill in the date gaps in the @sales table for each available date in @o_dates and this has to be for each code available available in the @sales table

Please, help with this select.

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE
(
code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
date1 DATETIME NOT NULL,
value NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @sales
(
Code,
Date1,
value
)
VALUES  ('q', '20140708', 51),
('q', '20140709', 3),
('q', '20140710', 5),
('q', '20140711', 6),
('q', '20140712', 2),
('q', '20140713', 7),
('q', '20140714', 24),
('q', '20140715', 24),
('x', '20140709', 25),
('x', '20140710', 16),
('x', '20140711', 66),
('x', '20140712', 23),
('x', '20140713', 35),
('x', '20140714', 57),
('c', '20140712', 97),
('c', '20140714', 71);

DECLARE @o_dates TABLE 
(date2 DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT  @o_dates
(date2)
VALUES  ('20140608'),
('20140707'),
('20140708'),
('20140709'),
('20140710'),
('20140711'),
('20140712'),
('20140713'),
('20140714'),
('20140715'),
('20140716'),
('20140717'),
('20140718'),
('20140719'),
('20140720');
```

Comment: What should the be in the `value` field of the rows added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gives you the combined sales and dates for each code with the value as null for the missing dates in sales:

```
select code, date1, value from @sales 
union (
    select distinct code, date2, null as value from @sales, @o_dates
    except
    select code, date1, null as value from @sales
    group by code, date1
) 
order by code, date1, value
```

This query inserts the dates that are missing in the sales table with 0 as value:

```
insert @sales 
select distinct code, date2, 0 as value from @sales, @o_dates
except
select code, date1, 0 as value from @sales
group by code, date1
```

I'm sure both queries can be simplified using joins but this was the first solution that I thought of.

Edit:

A join version of the select query above that should be easy to modify to an insert:

```
select distinct s.code, date2, s2.value from @sales s
cross join  @o_dates d
left join @sales s2
on s.code=s2.code and s2.date1=d.date2
order by code, date2
```

Comment: Hi jpw, more than happy to do so but before I need 15 reputation. I´ll do it asap.

Comment: @Louise01 You only need the 15 rep to vote up, you should be able to accept the answer at 1 rep by ticking the check mark. Accepting will also increase your own rep.